# Toold for vector-to-vector conversions (SVG/PDF to EMF/EPS)

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick

I used the `convert` of IM to translate svg to eps. But apparently ImageMagick rasterized it. Is there a mode to do vector-to-vector conversion?

Inkscape does not reproduce transparent areas and gradients properly and produces jagged edges. And it does not generate EMFs in Linux.

Is there any other tool that does vector-to-vector conversion well?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [pstoedit](http://www.pstoedit.net/) with some success.  It converts paths correctly but has some issues when converting text due to font handling.